# Can I directly connect a 5V DC device to the inputs or outputs of a 3.3V microcontroller that tolerate that voltage level?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, uart, 5v, 3.3v

I'm doing a project with a PIC32 that works with 3.3V and that has some terminals that are tolerant to 5V levels.

I need to manage another device that has a UART at TTL voltage levels (5v).

The terminal that would be transmitting data from the microcontroller would be configured as an open drain type output and would use a pull up resistor. While the receiving terminal of data from the microcontroller, I think I should just connect directly to the transmitting terminal of the other device.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frRgSC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This configuration gives me a bit of insecurity. I think there could be damage to the microcontroller terminals due to overvoltage,

I would think that I should add a few extra resistors to try to limit the current in some way similar to the diagram below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2OUq7.png)</sup>

Obviously, these additional resistors could be a problem if I want to transmit and receive data at high speeds, but at moderate speeds, I think that would not be a problem.

My question is: Is it necessary the precautions of the additional resistors?

Any comment or suggestion will be welcome

Regards

Comment: Where you have multiple DC supplies, *power supply sequencing* might be considered, where the MCU is potentially subject to latch-up. During power-up, I'd want the 3.3V MCU supply to come up before the 5V supply. This too might be excessively cautious for 5V-tolerant inputs, which should be less-subject to latch-up than normal I/O pins. The latch-up problem seems to be documented poorly in many MCU data sheets.

Comment: Are you sure the UART won't operate at 3.3V? What is the P/n ( datasheet link)?  All RS-232 Rx thresholds are 2 diode drops (TTL legacy) = 1.3V regardless of the Tx swing e.g. +/-15V

Comment: I don't know of any UART or RS-232 device **not** capable of  operating at 3.3V these days .!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you think you need the series resistors.

Even if you do put them in for protection they would not be the limiting factor in speed. They only need to be a few hundred ohms to limit the current to a safe level of 10-20mA.

The pull-up (R1) though could be a limitation.

Depending upon the capabilities of the MCU output pin R1 may not be lower than 1-2k ohms.

That value could slow down the signals somewhat. It would only only have an affect at multi-megahertz speeds though.

You don't say what speeds you are running at - the resistors should be no problem for normal UART speeds up to 115200 bps.

Comment: Thanks for answering. the speed is 9600bps. The pull up resistor was supposed to be approximately that value, although I will be able to test with what resistance value the other device recognizes as logical 1.

I also think there is a bug in both designs, the pull up resistor should be connected to 5V, not 3.3V.